# Socket OutputStream::write method mixes TCP packets?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

i have some problem with java socket.

I create simple proxy server which listen http request, transfer this request to source, and then return response, without disconnect. And sometimes client receive invalid data. I looked at tcp dump logs, and i found thet tcp packets was mixes

This is very simple code example

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 3000);

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

while (true) {
    final Request request = Request.read(in);
    if (request == null) return;

    try {
        // send http request 
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.factory(request);
        Response response = httpRequest.response();

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        buffer.write(response.headers.toString());
        buffer.write(response.body);

        out.write(buffer.toByteArray());
        out.flush();
    } catch (ParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

This is a screen tcp dump log, which you can see 3 http response in one tcp packet http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0009/2601/629289/150827/004858080b.jpg

Why is this happening, and how to solve this problem ?

**Update 28.10.2015 17:50**

*Sorry guys, it was my fault on the server side. Java worked perfectly*

Comment: This is no way to write a proxy. You're introducing all kinds of unnecessary latency. All that I/O could have been done straight to the output stream. The ByteArrayOutputStream contributes nothing. But you don't need the HTTP Request object either. Once you've read the first line from the client, the rest is just copying bytes back and forth.

Comment: Thx for the answer. This code is very very simple, and written only for example. In real project, it's not simple proxy, it's multi connections with multithreading and a lot of business logic

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the expected, correct behavior. The `Connection: keep-alive` header means that the connection is kept open so that it can be used for more than one HTTP request. If it's combined with pipelining, the responses may even come in a single TCP segment.

Comment: I hurried with congratulate :(. I remove keep-alive, but it's not helped to me :(

Comment: Keep-alive is the default, you have to set  Connection: close  to have the connection closed.

Comment: Can you produce a minimal self contained example that shows the problem? Your sample above does not even create a ServerSocket